# Intellisense in visual studio for app engine python project

Tags: python, visual-studio, google-app-engine, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to have intellisense support for my python app engine project in visual studio 2015(community edition ptvs installed)

How I could achive this?

What I have tried is:

I installed `ndb` for `from google.appengine.ext import ndb` with pip which seems ok for intellisense:

`from google.appengine.ext.ndb import msgprop`
becomes
`from ndb import msgprop`

and

`D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` has `ndb` and `ndb-1.0.13b1.dist-info`

I don't think when I upload to app engine this will work

Answer (score 0):

Add folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine resolves issue:

[image]

and project looks like

[image]

Do not forget restart VS 2015 to get intellisense.

Then in order to void upload this folder to app engine in app.yaml add section:

```
skip_files:
- ^(google)
```